# hide a baseclass public method with new modifier

Tags: c#

I have class myCollection that inherit from Dictionary.
Want to hide the add method in myCollection. 
Used the private new modifier but its still visible.
Is this not possible ?

baseclass

> ```
>     public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>     {
>         Insert(key, value, true);
>     }
> ```

mycollection

> ```
>     private new void Add(string key, MyOtherClass myClass)
>     {
>         base.Add(key, myClass);    
>     }
> ```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to hide it.

Comment: If you need to hide an inherited function and change its accessibility, it's generally because there's a flaw in the design of your program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can't change the accessibility of an inherited member.

You can use composition instead of inheritance and only expose the functionality you want (by delegating calls to the composed object). This may not be an option if you rely on the inheritance chain elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hidden because the method signature of the Add in baseclass doesn't match that of the method in the mycollection class.

Comment: From the signature of the baseclass I assume these are generic parameters (TKey, TValue). Nothing wrong with the derived class using actual generic types.

Comment: Oh interesting, I hadn't considered that. Thanks for the explanation.